# Azure Dev Ops Deploying Application Error?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I was trying to deploy an API(.net core 2) to App Service using Azure DevOps Pipeline.
The pipeline was able to run successfully but when I'm trying to send a http request or browse the deployed API application it only shows an application error. Can someone please help my pinpoint the problem?

Note: Im only using azure STUDENT subscription and the default template for the .net core 2 API application in Visual Studio

**My Pipeline:**

[image]

**Picture of successful pipeline build:**
[image]

**The error showing when im browsing the api application**
[image]

Comment: Deploying new resources to azure is restricted to free subscription

Comment: @Sajeetharan Hi so i should assume that my deployment was successful but due to the restriction i wont be able to use the web app?

Comment: @Sajeetharan note im using student subscription if that what free means

Comment: @user2572367 Did you check the application log?

Comment: Hi @Bimal I have already tried tracing it in the ftp logs files but cant seem to find relevant issue or i maybe im browsing the wrong files

Comment: Can you go to `https://yourWebappName.scm.azurewebsites.net` to check if the source app files exit in `wwwroot` folder in the server and the files are in the right structure?